# In short I really struggle with syntax, can somebody help me fix this?

Tags: c++

so i need to read in a file, then create a word count and a character count for each time the character appears using an array.  each word ends with whitespace, comma, period, etc.  also i need to put a tolower and an equation to set the letters to the right array with an x-'a' function or something like that.

list of errors from puTTy(crappy program i know but it's required)

> project8.cpp: In function âint main()â:
>   project8.cpp:17: error: âfile1â was not declared in this scope
>   project8.cpp:18: error: expected â;â before âwhileâ
>   project8.cpp:36: error: expected â}â at end of input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    int in_word = false;
    int word_count = 0;
    char ch;
    char low_case;
    int char_count[26];
    int i;

int main()
{
    for (i=0; i<26; i++)
    char_count[i]=0;

cin.get(file1.txt)
while('\n' !=(ch=cin.get(file1.txt)))
{
if (' ' == ch || '\n' == ch || '\t' == ch)
    in_word = false;
else if (in_word == false)
    {
    in_word=true;
    word_count++;
    }
else low_case=tolower(ch);
    char_count[int(low_case)-int('a')]++;
}

cout << file1.txt;
cout << words << " words" << endl;
for (i=0; i<26; i++)
    if(count[i] !=0)
    cout << count[i] << " " << char(i+'a') << endl;
}
```

Comment: What's actually wrong with this program as is?  Most IDE's will give you lost of syntax help.

Comment: Your question is too general for StackOverflow, it is not a website where you dump an issue such as 'fix this program for me'.

Comment: "project8"? So you got through 7 projects already without knowing about the need to put quotes around a literal filename or a semicolon at the end of a line? Or you just got some sucker to do all the work for you but now they've quit helping?

Answer (score 1):

Let's play compiler!

You cannot name a variable `file1.txt`, call it `file1`

Also, you forgot the semi-colon `;` at the end of the line, so

```
cin.get(file1.txt)
```

should be

```
cin.get(file1);
```

I don't quite know where you are defining this variable, so you may be missing a declaration like

```
const char* file1="file1.txt";
```

Furthermore, you start trying to access some variable `count` after your for-loop here:

```
count[i]
```

Did you mean to use `char_count`?

Comment: since you changed the code I removed the comments. Of course, a new comment is: the initialization of the 26 character was actually correct without any parenthesis...!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Man, racing to answer SO questions first is really killing my quality.

Comment: yeah, seems so. BTW, note that the initialization `char* file1 = "file1.txt";` is illegal in C++ (starting with the C++11 revision; before that this initialization was merely deprecated). Surely you wanted to write `char const* file1 = "file1.txt";`

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I actually did not know this was part of the standard change. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you haven't declared `file1`. It is somewhat unclear what `file1.txt` really is meant to be: The way it is written, it seems to be an object of type with a member called, `txt` of type `char*` or `char[N]` (with a constant `N`). From the looks of it, you actually wanted to open a file named `file1.txt`. This would look like so:

```
std::ifstream in("file1.txt");
```

After that you would, of course, use `in` instead of `std::cin` to read from the file. For example you could use

```
for (char c; in.get(c); ) {
    // ...
}
```

to read each individual character of the file and process it appropriately.

Comment: +1 for addressing the deeper issues rather than the syntactical ones.